# Java JPA enum-like String options

Tags: java, security, jpa, enums

I am trying to implement a simple User-Roles relationship in a Spring application, for security. The basic entities (some fields and annotations trimmed):

**User**

```
@Table(name="usr")
public class User implements Serializable {
  @Id
  private UUID id;
  @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinTable(name="user_roles", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
    inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
  private Collection<Role> roles;
}
```

**Role**

```
public class Role implements Serializable {
  @Id
  private UUID id;
  @ManyToMany(mappedBy="roles")
  private Collection<User> users;
  private String name;
}
```

So far, so good. However, I also have a class that defines a list of role-name values:

**UserRoles**

```
public class UserRole {
 public static final String ADMIN = "admin";
 public static final String USER = "user";
}
```

I want to constrain the values of the `Role`'s `name` field to the values in `UserRoles`, effectively like an enum.

These `role` values will get used within Spring Security functions that require roles to be string values. As such, if I were to make `UserRoles` an enum, any database storage would be of `int`s – the ordinal definition position within `UserRoles` – which would force me to keep any potentially deprecated options, and also require a hacky conversion every time I need to convert the `role` to a string that can be passed around in a JWT, etc. (If I want to look at my database directly, it will also be far less informative.)

Is there some way to define `Role`'s name field as limited to the static values in `UserRoles`? (Changing how or where these values are stored is entirely acceptable.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can define like this**

```
public enum UserRoleEnum {
  USER, ADMIN
}
```

**And in entity**

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
private UserRoleEnum role;
```

Comment: Thanks. Though I suspect you meant `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` as I specifically said I wanted to avoid ordinals. Your answer did lead me to https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-persisting-enums-in-jpa, which provided me with the JPA 2.1 `@Converter` approach. Update accodingly for acceptance.